# USE Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently using `USE [databaseName]` in my **stored procedures**. However, is there a way that I can point this at the current local database and not give a database name? I know this may sound a bit obscure but its highly likely that I will be using these Stored Procedures in many different databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `USE [databaseName]` from your stored procedure.

By default, the stored procedure will run on the current database (in which SP is created)